# Function gives me raw column data (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

I'm working with Laravel and I want to display the created_at timestamp formatted of course, but only where id = 1, so the latest one.

```
public function statistics(){

  $first = DB::table('articles')
                 ->select('created_at')
                 ->where('id', '=', 1)
                 ->get();

  return view('pages.statistics')->with('first', $first);;

}
```

blade:

```
{{ $first}}
```

I want to have a formatted date, but when I use the date function it automatically sets the date to 01.01.1970

This is what I get:

[{"created_at":"2018-08-23 11:45:34"}]

Should I work with Carbon and if yes, how?

Comment: can you explain more? where do you format date coming from database??

Comment: You need to get this by $first->created_at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
public function statistics(){

    $first = DB::table('articles')
             ->select('created_at')
             ->where('id', '=', 1)
             ->first();

    return view('pages.statistics')->with('first', $first);

}
```

Then in your view, you can do `$first->created_at`. You can also pass this into `Carbon` to format it how you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is a json array you can try

```
$first=json_decode($first,true);
```

And then send `$first[0]['created_at']` in your view

This will return only the date field you are looking for *2018-08-23 11:45:34*.

Answer (score 0):

First off: 
If you are not getting an instance of a eloquent model the dates will not be cast into a Carbon object.

Is article a Eloquent Model? If so you should go about it this way:

in model:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at'];
```

in controller:

```
$article = \App\Article::where('id',1)->get()
return view('pages.statistics')->with('article', $article);
```

And in blade:

```
{{$article->created_at}}
```

or if you want to access carbon object

```
{{article->created_at->format('M-d')}}
```

If article is not an eloquent-model (sounds like it should be though) you have to create the Carbon object manually like so:

```
$first = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s',$first->first()->created_at)
```